# PlayOnLinux not run

Tags: playonlinux

I'm trying install `Playonlinux` in my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

I have installed `PlayonLinux` with

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

so that is installed, but when I'll run, it's not run, and no error message

And when I'll try close with right click in dock icon, this show me a message 'You can close this window'

How to can I fix this problem?

---

Result of run in terminal:

```
> playonlinux
Looking for python... 2.7.6 - selected
[main] Message: PlayOnLinux (4.2.2) is starting
[clean_tmp] Message: Cleaning temp directory
[POL_System_CheckFS] Message: Checking filesystem for /home/lai32290/.PlayOnLinux/
[main] Message: Filesystem is compatible
[install_plugins] Message: Checking plugin: ScreenCap...
[install_plugins] Message: Checking plugin: PlayOnLinux Vault...
[POL_SetupWindow_Init] Message: Creating new window for pid 14719
[maj_check] Message: List is up to date
```

Comment: How did you run it ?

Comment: Try to run it from terminal, run the command `playonlinux` and list down the output

Comment: @markkirby I run it with dock icon

Comment: @Maythux How to can I run it with terminal? When I try run the command 'playonlinux', this is return me message 'PlayOnLinux is not supposed to be run as root. Sorry'

Comment: What is the output of the command `ls -l /usr/bin/playonlinux`

Comment: do NOT run it at root! as it says.....

Comment: I updated my post, add result of run playonlinux in terminal

Comment: @Maythux  ls -l return me '-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 62 Out  6  2009 /usr/bin/playonlinux'

Comment: @Lai32290 output of command `whoami`?

Comment: @Maythux whoami return me 'lai32290'

Comment: @Lai32290 everything is just ok and from the terminal output it's already running,. Are you sure it's not shown?!

Comment: @Maythux I don't know why, but now, I will take a prints screen to show you, but in my print screen is showing PlayOnLinux window, but I can see it, PlayOnLinux is in center screen

Comment: Check other workspaces

Comment: @Maythux I found it! Sorry for everybody. I'm very very beginner in Linux

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26063/discussion-between-lai32290-and-maythux).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Result of run in terminal:

```
$ playonlinux

Looking for python... 2.7.6 - selected
[main] Message: PlayOnLinux (4.2.2) is starting
[clean_tmp] Message: Cleaning temp directory
[POL_System_CheckFS] Message: Checking filesystem for /home/lai32290/.PlayOnLinux/
[main] Message: Filesystem is compatible
[install_plugins] Message: Checking plugin: ScreenCap...
[install_plugins] Message: Checking plugin: PlayOnLinux Vault...
[POL_SetupWindow_Init] Message: Creating new window for pid 14719
[maj_check] Message: List is up to date
```

From all above comments and the output of `playonlinux`  command, it seems it's already running so mostly it will be located in another workspace, so just move to other workspaces and check it.